# Can I backup config of an EdgeRouter Lite 3 to an EdgeRouter 4?

Tags: router, network, hardware, ubiquiti

After having worked 6 years and 24/7, my `EdgeRouter Lite 3` have definitely died. I want to replace it by a new `EdgeRouter 4`.

Can I easily use my `EdgeRouter Lite 3` backup files and import it to a new `Edge Router 4` ? Will I find the same configuration on the `ERL-4` first three ports?

I think yes, because `ERL-3` have only 3 ports, and `ER-4` have one more. The fourth port will not be used for the moment.

Comment: My EdgeRouter Lite 3 has died several times. Each time it's brought back to life by replacing the internal USB drive that it uses. Using something like dd to copy it over (dd-rescue if needed) has usually worked, though I've also had to resort to rebuilding the full image from a firmware download. Thankfully this project at https://github.com/sowbug/mkeosimg can combine the firmware with an exported config to get you back up and running really quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem migrating from an `ERL3` to an `ER4` because interfaces names between these routers are the same.

After migration, we have to manually create the interface eth3 (because eth3 doesn't exist on EdgeRouter Lite) like this :

```
configure
set interfaces ethernet eth3 speed auto
set interfaces ethernet eth3 duplex auto
commit
save
```

After that, reboot EdgeRouter a couple of times and everything will work perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, your question is not fully allowed here due to the device manufacturer (Ubiquiti) not offering any sort of paid support option.

However, as a generic/brand-agnostic question, if you can export the config to a flat text file, yes, you can move between models.  You will likely have to account for making a few changes, though, such as interface names and numbering’s being potentially different (FastEthernet to GigabitEthernet, or 1/1 to 0/1). As long as you pay attention to stuff like that, you should be safe.

Comment: I’m sorry about that ! So I’m going to ask my question on the manufacturer’s forums. The `ERL-3` backups files are zipped. When I unzip and open a file, I have a lot of files and directories, but one called `config.boot` seems to contain all the configuration in text format (firewall rules, interfaces, static mapping...). Between the two routers, interfaces names must be the same I guess. If not, I just need to edit the configuration in text format with the new interface names. Do I understand correctly ?

Comment: @Loraga Pretty much. Having worked on a few Ubiquiti devices before, I know that the switches can be managed via CLI (not just the web UI) so I’m assuming their routers can as well.  If so, you can dump the output to a flat text file that way rather than using the web UI’s export option.

Comment: I have successfully restored `ER-3` configuration on my new `ER-4`. There is just two little things to do after backup. Must I post solution as answer here ?

Comment: @Loraga If you’d like to, you can.